# Unity: Issue with serialization since version 5.0 (Parent/Children relationship)

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

when I was using older versions of Unity there was no problem, but since uppgrade I keep receiving errors on all classes where class contains children of its type: Serialization depth limit exceeded at 'Formation'. There may be an object composition cycle in one or more of your serialized classes.

I have a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Formation {
    public List<Formation> Formations;
}
```

It writes about some cycles, but why there would be any problem when there is no infinite cycle, because every child instance must be initialized, so if user wants to make infinite cycle he would do it, but only by initializing children explicitly...

Is this some bug? I read already some thread on forum suggesting removing children, but I don't get why this behavior even occurs.

Btw on this class I wrote last time I didn't even serialize, and didn't even make list instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue of cyclic serialization. I solved it by explicitly making the parent instance nonserializable.

e.g.

```
[Serializable]
class A
{
    [SerializeField]
    B _bInstance;
    ...
}
...
[Serializable]
class B
{
    A _aInstance;
    ...
}
```

becomes

```
[Serializable]
class A
{
    [SerializeField]
    B _bInstance;
    ...
}
...
[Serializable]
class B
{
    [NonSerialized]
    A _aInstance;
    ...
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty obvious to be honest... It's because of what happens when you perform serialization. Just go with me: you have a class `Formation`, which contains a collection of `Formation`s. Those are of type `Formation`, so they each have a collection. And so on... The cycle is virtually infinite.

```
Formation
     List
           Formation
                 List
                      Formation
                                List
                                      ....
```

Easiest fix is to move the collection to a more meaningful class (outside Formation). I don't think that `Formation` should have a List inside it of more `Formation`s anyway...

Comment: This one was actually for testing purpose because I was working on new class and wanted to test nesting - in other cases I have parent/child relationship is more meaningful. Anyway it is not very obvious for me because I didn't have actual objects there - just empty list of type Formation - does serialization automatically try to create new lists and fill it? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Well yes, the problem is obvious, but just because there COULD be a self reference, or a very deep depth, doesn't mean there will be one. The BinaryFormatter serializes this model just fine. And if you plan to use that, and never even ask unity to serilize the it, it still shows the error just for having the code in your project. Kind of annoying.

Comment: Seems like a dumb implementation to me... You only need to actually serialize the children if there are any. If the collection is `null` or empty, why would you bother iterating down through a type hierarchy you're not going to use?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this problem can be solved by storing all your objects that can have children of the same type in a Container that will handle children-parents relationships on serialization.
Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Serializable]
public class MyObject
{
    [NonSerializeble]
    public MyObject child;
}

//this is the class that you are going to serialize
[Serializable]
public class ObjectsContrainer
{
    private List<MyObject> allObjects;
    private List<serializationInfo> serializationInfos;

    //save info about the children in a way that we dont get any cycles
    [OnSerializing]
    private void OnSerializingStarted(StreamingContext context)
    {
        serializationInfos = new List<serializationInfo>();
        foreach (var obj in allObjects)
        {
            serializationInfo info = new serializationInfo {
                parentIndex = allObjects.FindIndex(x => x == obj),
                childIndex =  allObjects.FindIndex(x => x == obj.child)
            serializationInfos.Add(info);
        }
    }

    //restore info about the children
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(object o)
    {
        //restore connections
        foreach (var info in serializationInfos)
        {
            var parent = allObjects[info.parentIndex];
            parent.child = allObjects[info.childIndex];
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    private struct serializationInfo
    {
        public int childIndex;
        public int parentIndex;
    }
}
```